# ClassNotFoundException when extending a class

Tags: android, nativescript

I am working on a NativeScript Stripe plugin, using TypeScript. It's working on iOS, now trying to get it working on Android.

I have been able to successfully extend some Android classes (following [Extending Classes](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface)). One, though, gives ClassNotFoundException when it is being constructed.

I created a .d.ts file using android-dts-generator. It gives the signature of the class I'm extending as (abbreviated):

```
declare module com {
  export module stripe {
    export module android {
      export class PaymentSession {
        export class PaymentSessionListener {
          public constructor();
          public onError(param0: number, param1: string): void;
          ...
        }}}}}
```

I extend as follows:

```
class InternalPaymentListener extends com.stripe.android.PaymentSession.PaymentSessionListener {
  constructor() {
    super();
    return global.__native(this);
  }
  init(p1, p2): InternalPaymentListener { ...; return this; }
  ...
}
```

When I try to construct this, using `new InternalPaymentListener().init(p1, p2)` I get a ClassNotFoundException:

```
JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tns.gen.com.stripe.android.PaymentSession_PaymentSessionListener_stripe_148_28_InternalPaymentListener
JS:     java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
JS:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
JS:     java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.getClassForName(Runtime.java:1023)
JS:     com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:27)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.resolveClass(Runtime.java:593)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1101)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:983)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:970)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:954)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:946)
JS:     com.tns.gen.java.lang.Object_button_19_32_ClickListenerImpl.onClick(Object_button_19_32_ClickListenerImpl.java:17)
JS:     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
JS:     android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
JS:     android....
```

The generated stripe.js file has at line 148 (which I assume is what the exception is pointing me to):

```
function InternalPaymentListener() {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;    <-- Line 148
    return global.__native(_this);
}
```

The code compiles without error or warning, so you'd think the class got generated properly. It runs until I click the button that results in this class being constructed.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the answer to my own question, so quickly I'm almost embarrassed for asking in the first place!

It turns out `PaymentSessionListener` is an interface, not a class. I was confused by the .d.ts definition generated by android-dts-generator. This is how to correctly implement the interface (as documented at [Extending Classes](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/binding-generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces)):

```
function createListener() {
  return new com.stripe.android.PaymentSession.PaymentSessionListener({
    onError(param0: number, param1: string): void { ... }
    ...
  });
}
```